# Создать функцию для сортировки массива на PHP

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Есть массив:

```
$deliveryMethodsArray = [
    [
        'code' => 'dhl',
        'customer_costs' => [
            22 => '1.000',
            11 => '3.000',
        ]
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'fedex',
        'customer_costs' => [
            22 => '4.000',
            11 => '6.000',
        ]
    ]];
```

И нужно создать для нее функцию сортировки.
Вот вывод

```
$result = sortfunc($deliveryMethodsArray)
var_dump($result);
```

```
array(2)
 {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "4.000"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}
```

Вот что у меня в данный момент поучилось но не могу вывести как в примере

Вот код:

```
function sortFunc($deliveryMethodsArray)
{

    foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $names, 'code' => $codes]) {
        foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $name, 'code' => $code]) {
            foreach ($names as $keys => $b) {
                foreach ($name as $key => $a) {
                    $value [$keys] = [$codes => $b] + [$code => $a];
                }
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }
return $deliveryMethodsArray;
}
```

А вот что выводит:

```
array(2) {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}
```

Не знаю что дальше делать
Если есть варианты или решение то можете подсказать?

Comment: функция сортировки меняет последовательность следования элементов массива. У вас же на выходе совершенно другой массив

Comment: Задание выглядит вот так и я не знаю как придумать функцию сортировки

Comment: никак. Потому что сортировка не может менять элементы массива

Comment: Просто я так понял что оно должно сортировать по ключу. В примере берем ключ 22 и 11 и по нему сортируем ключ code и оно должно выводить массив по ключу 22 в котором выводит 2 ключа code (dhl,fedex) и число по которому был ключ 22

Comment: сортировка не меняет значений массива, только порядок их следования. У вас вообще меняется выходной массив. Функция сортировки так делать не должна и не может

Comment: Так а что нужно тогда сделать что бы получился такой массив?

Comment: для начала получить выходной массив. Можно с неправильной сортировкой.  Для этого пробегитесь циклом и соберите новый выходной массив. А вот уже дальше можно будет применить функцию сортировки.

Comment: Вот что у меня получилось 

    `foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $name, 'code' => $code]) {
            foreach ($name as $key => $a) {
                $value = [$key => [$code => $a]];
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($value);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }`

Comment: Вот что выводит на экран:
`array(1) {
  [22]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [11]=>
  array(1) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [22]=>
  array(1) {
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "4.000"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [11]=>
  array(1) {
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}`
Но я не знаю как мне объединить похожие массивы и перекинуть их в один массив