# Не получается вывести массив так как в примере

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Есть массив:

```
$deliveryMethodsArray = [
    [
        'code' => 'dhl',
        'customer_costs' => [
            22 => '1.000',
            11 => '3.000',
        ]
    ],
    [
        'code' => 'fedex',
        'customer_costs' => [
            22 => '4.000',
            11 => '6.000',
        ]
    ]];
```

И нужно создать для нее функцию сортировки. Вот вывод

```
$result = sortfunc($deliveryMethodsArray)
var_dump($result);
```

```
array(2)
 {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "4.000"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}
```

Вот что у меня в данный момент поучилось но не могу вывести как в примере

Вот код:

```
function sortFunc($deliveryMethodsArray)
{

    foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $names, 'code' => $codes]) {
        foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $name, 'code' => $code]) {
            foreach ($names as $keys => $b) {
                foreach ($name as $key => $a) {
                    $value [$keys] = [$codes => $b] + [$code => $a];
                }
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }
return $deliveryMethodsArray;
}
```

А вот что выводит:

```
array(2) {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dhl"]=>
    string(5) "3.000"
    ["fedex"]=>
    string(5) "6.000"
  }
}
```

Не знаю что дальше делать Если есть варианты или решение то можете подсказать?

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Создать функцию для сортировки массива на PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1440564/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php)

Comment: Этот deliveryMethodsArray структурой всегда постоянный ? в реальной задаче? не будет потом появляется еще второй блок [
    [
        'code' => 'dhl1'......

Comment: 22 , 11 тоже постоянны или меняются?

Comment: Если структура и идентификаторы в массиве постоянны, то как по мне легче не циклами крутить и собирать, а легче просто новое лакало массива написать, и в него тупа присвоить значения из первого.Если конечно значения структуры и идентификаторы в массиве меняются то уже надо конкретно знать по каким правилам.

Comment: Я не могу сказать постоянны они или нет так как задача была поставлена такова как я ее и написал. Есть массив и вывод функцией. Было бы круче если бы можно было менять ключи массива но вот не знаю как вывести правильно и что бы получилось

Comment: Если есть идеи то подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачку

Comment: Simon да это дубликат вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю у меня получилось но не совсем правильно.
Если вы знаете как решить эту задачу иным способом то подскажите как ее решить по другому)

````
```
function sortFunc($deliveryMethodsArray)
{

    foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $names, 'code' => $codes]) {
        foreach ($deliveryMethodsArray as ["customer_costs" => $name, 'code' => $code]) {
                foreach ($names as $keys => $b) {
                    foreach ($name as $key => $a) {
                        if ($b == '1.000') {
                            $value [$key] = [$codes => $b]+[$code => $a];
                        }
                        else{
                            $value [$keys] = [$code => $a];
                        }
                    }
                    if ($b == '3.000') {
                        $value [$keys] = [$codes => $b] + [$code => $a];
                    }
                    else{
                        $value [$key] = [$code => $a];
                    }
                }
        }
        return $value;
    }

return $deliveryMethodsArray;
}
```
```
$result = sortFunc($deliveryMethodsArray);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```
````